# Inserting into Remote Db via Dblink

Tags: postgresql, intervals, insertion, dblink

***I'm trying to insert into remote DB via this query***

*The query works fine When I only select these columns but when I'm trying to insert with a 30-day interval condition it shows that an error in syntax
I don't know What I'm doing wrong in the interval syntax for selecting data of 30 days.
Can anyone help me with this!
Thanks*

```
INSERT INTO tc_new_events
SELECT * FROM dblink ('dev_connec','SELECT id,type,eventtime,
deviceid,positionid,geofenceid,
attributes,maintenanceid FROM tc_events
WHERE eventTime < (NOW() - '30 days' INTERVAL  )') 
AS DATA (id int ,type varchar , eventtime timestamp without time zone , 
deviceid integer,positionid integer,geofenceid integer ,
attributes varchar,maintenanceid integer);
```

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "30"
LINE 13: ...anceid FROM tc_events WHERE eventTime < (NOW() - '30 days' I...
                                                              ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 994
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO tc_new_events
SELECT * FROM dblink ('dev_connec','SELECT id,type,eventtime,deviceid,positionid,geofenceid,attributes,maintenanceid FROM tc_events WHERE eventTime < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 days ') AS DATA (id int ,type varchar , eventtime timestamp without time zone , deviceid integer,positionid integer,geofenceid integer ,attributes varchar,maintenanceid integer);`

Comment: The quotes around the interval are interfering with the quotes around the entire query string.  You can escape the interior quote marks by doubling them, or switch one set or the other (or both but with different delimiters) to using dollar-quoting style.